# IBM JsonStore FindAll with filter ot without Filter not working in IOS when the records count is 50k

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

Hi I have a JSONSTORE with encryption enabled and i have a Store called Assets in this i store upto 50k+ records and i try to retrieve the all the records unique value using Filter option in the JSONStore and **it works perfectly in the android devices** but when it comes to IOS the API keeps on loading without any result / error.

`WL.JSONStore.get("Assets").findAll({filter : ["ASSETID"]})
WL.JSONStore.get("Assets").findAll()`

I am using Cordova IOS -> 4.5.4
JSONStore Plugin -> 8.0.2019121604 (Tried latest as well same result)

Comment: Android and iOS have different memory management schemes ( managed entirely by the OS).Does it work well with small units? May be 20 K or even upto 50K.

Comment: Sorry I haven't tried it will give it a shot

Comment: @VivinK for 10k - 30sec , 20k - 1min, 30k - 1m30sec to fetch the data for 40k itself it never returned any result for almost 5 min

Answer (score -1):

Can you explain why you're trying to load 50k records into memory ? This is typically bad design and there is no way 50k records are needed in the app at a given time. You should always query the subset of records you're interested in. 
If you want to display all 50k in a list, you should still paginate your results and display them.

The behavior depends on the memory available on the device, plus the memory management of iOS.

Furthermore, loading so many records will cause iOS to terminate background apps leading to poor experience for your users.

Comment: Hi don't come to conclusions please ask for explanation we aren't trying to load the entire jsonstore collection we just need a single key value pair of all the records and we need that because we are comparing it with the DB to cross verify we are having all the updated records

Comment: Well, the findAll() API mentioned in the question does load all the records into memory.